# Sorting of string as per its insertion

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Scenario: I have table with single column (string). I want to retrieve data which are stored in particular order.

table Tbl_EmployeeName having only one column 'Name'

I inserted records through this below query

```
Insert Into Tbl_EmployeeName
select 'Z'
union
select 'y'
union
select 'x'
union 
select 'w'
union
select 'v'
union
select 'u'
union
select 't'
union
select 's'
```

Now I want these records in the same order in which it is inserted. 
when i run the query:

```
select * from Tbl_EmployeeName
```

it will arrange the records in default order by Name asc.
i.e.

result output

```
s                                                
t                                                
u                                               
v                                               
w                                              
x                                                 
y                                                 
Z
```

I want all records in this way

expected output

```
z
y
x
w
v
u
t
s
```

Could you please suggest me is there any way to get this in proper sequence in which records are entered, and also without adding any new column to a table.

Comment: yes, use an autonumeric column

Comment: Without modifying your table to add an `IDENTITY` column, this is not possible.  SQL tables represent *unordered sets*.  Without something to order them by, the order is *not* guaranteed.

Comment: like the ones before me... IDENTITY column. It auto increments on each insert telling you exactly the order of insertion.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? Please remove the unnecessary tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort it in your own order with **FIND_IN_SET**

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tbl_EmployeeName 
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(Name,'Z,y,x,w,v,u,t,s');
```

If you dont know the insert order use this, then there is direct a AUTOINCREMENT field.

```
CREATE TABLE `Tbl_EmployeeName` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


    SELECT * 
    FROM Tbl_EmployeeName 
ORDER by id;
```

Comment: Thanks Bernd, but in my case I don't know the user input so this doesn't help me.

Comment: I have change my answer

Answer (score 1):

> I inserted records through this below query
>
> `...query using union...`
>
> Now I want these records in the same order in which it is inserted.

Surprisingly, you *are* retrieving the records in the order in which they were inserted.  Using `UNION` between each of the `SELECT` statements on your `INSERT` is causing the records to be sorted *before* being inserted.  `UNION` does an inherent `DISTINCT` over all of the results.  Switching this to `UNION ALL` will eliminate the inherent ordering.

HOWEVER...

> Could you please suggest me is there any way to get this in proper sequence in which records are entered, **and also without adding any new column to a table.**

Unfortunately, this is *not* possible.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  It has no native concept over either the order of the records or the order of which they were inserted.

> When I run the query `select * from Tbl_EmployeeName`
>   it will arrange the records in default order by Name asc.

This is false.  As mentioned above, there is *no* default order that is returned.  Any result that you may have gotten when executing that query is merely coincidental.  Without specifying an `ORDER BY` clause, the order is *not* guaranteed.

> Could you please suggest me is there any way to get this in proper sequence in which records are entered

Contrary to your question, you *can* do this by adding a new column to your table.  By setting up the table as follows:

```
Create Table Tbl_EmployeeName 
(
    Id    Int Identity(1,1) Not Null,
    Name  Varchar (10) -- Or whatever your size is
);
```

Then doing your inserts:

```
Insert  Tbl_EmployeeName 
        (Name)
Values  ('Z'),
        ('y'),
        ('x'),
        ('w'),
        ('v'),
        ('u'),
        ('t'),
        ('s')
```

And querying:

```
Select  Name
From    Tbl_EmployeeName
Order By Id Asc
```

Comment: Is the order of insertion even guaranteed there? I would think that the results of that `SELECT` query would also be unordered (although MySQL might be consistent). Probably not a big deal, since the actual inserts will likely be at completely different times in the "real world" of course.

Comment: @TomH Hmm, quite possibly not.  I usually tend to avoid the `UNION ALL` insert syntax myself.  I'll update with a more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the order in which rows are returned in a result set are not guaranteed unless an ORDER BY clause is specified. [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx)

You'll need to add a new column if possible which will store the entry time, or a sequence which you can order on.

I would recommend a key/sequence as this can then be used to join other tables more efficiently ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)).